# Irreducible closed set, local property?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $Y \subset X$ be a connected closed subset of a scheme $(X,\mathcal O_X)$. If $Y \cap U$ is irreducible inside $U$, for every affine $U \subset X$, then is it true that $Y$ is irreducible inside $X$?

Comment: What is the notion of “irreducible *inside* something”? Can you give a reference?

Comment: @k.stm I imagine that the OP means $Y\cap U$ is an irreducible subset of $U$. You're right that irreducibility is an intrinsic topological property, but the context doesn't seem too offensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. If a connected set $Y$ has multiple irreducible components, then two of them, say $Y_1,Y_2$, must meet at a point $y$. Take some affine open neighborhood $U\subset X$ of $y$. Then $U\cap Y = (U\cap Y_1)\cup(U\cap Y_2)$ which demonstrates that $U\cap Y$ is reducible. To see that $U\cap Y\neq U\cap Y_i$, note that if this was true, then $U\cap Y_i \supset U\cap Y_j$, and then taking closures $Y_i\supset Y_j$, which is impossible since no irreducible component is contained in any other irreducible component. So your claim is correct.

Comment: It is not clear at all to me why $U \cap Y$ is reducible. How do you rule out that $U \cap Y = U \cap Y_1$ or $U \cap Y = U \cap Y_2$?

Comment: $U\cap Y_i$ is a nonempty open subset of $Y_i$ for both choices of $i$, so what you describe can't happen because we assumed $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ were distinct.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time, but I don't get it. Yes $U \cap Y_i$ are relatively open, yes $Y_1,Y_2$ are distinct, but how this implies the conclusion I have no idea. Care to expand your answer?

Comment: If $U\cap Y = U\cap Y_1$, then $U\cap Y_1 \supset U\cap Y_2$ which implies that $Y_1\supset Y_2$ after taking closures, as $\overline{U\cap Y_i}=Y_i$ since every nonempty open subset of an irreducible set is dense. But no irreducible component is contained in another irreducible component.

Comment: Much more clear. One last question however: what guarantees the existence of irreducible components? I thought you needed a Noetherian top space for that.

Comment: You do not need a noetherian topological space - an argument in the style of Zorn's lemma works just fine. See [Stacks 004W](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/004W) for instance.

Comment: @Hammerhead is there a reason that you have accepted this answer but not voted on it?